# React Bootstrap Tabs error given was: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

Deals.js

```
import {Tab, Nav, NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';
const Deals = (props) => {
  return (
<div>
<Tab.Container id="tabs-with-dropdown" defaultActiveKey="first">
  <Nav bsStyle="tabs">
    <NavItem eventKey="first">
      <span>props.hedding1</span>
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey="second">
      <span>props.hedding2</span>
    </NavItem>
  </Nav>
  <Tab.Content animation>
    <Tab.Pane eventKey="first">
      <span>Tab 1 content</span>
    </Tab.Pane>
    <Tab.Pane eventKey="second">
      <span>Tab 2 content</span>
    </Tab.Pane>
  </Tab.Content>
</Tab.Container>

<Tab.Container id="tabs-with-dropdown" defaultActiveKey="first">
  <Nav bsStyle="tabs">
    <NavItem eventKey="first">
      <span>Tab 1</span>
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey="second">
      <span>Tab 2</span>
    </NavItem>
  </Nav>
  <Tab.Content animation>
    <Tab.Pane eventKey="first">
      <span>Tab 1 content</span>
    </Tab.Pane>
    <Tab.Pane eventKey="second">
      <span>Tab 2 content</span>
    </Tab.Pane>
  </Tab.Content>
 </Tab.Container>
</div>
);
};
export default Deals;
```

I am getting eror like this:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of
>   `Deals`.

Error given was:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined.
>   Check the render method of `Deals`.

Comment: Show your full components code.